# Bootstrapping user into grails spring security with CAS

Tags: grails, spring-security, cas, shibboleth

I have a grails app forwarding to CAS and returning to the app, but I cant seem to move on to the protected controller. I thought I'd bootstrap a user (one I know can be authenticated by CAS) but I get the below error.

Grails 2.2.3, spring-security-core 2.0-RC2, spring-security-ccas 2.0-RC1

```
ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: Could not find matching constructor for: AppUser(java.util.LinkedHashMap, java.lang.Boolean, java.lang.Boolean, java.lang.Boolean, java.lang.Boolean)
Message: Could not find matching constructor for: AppUser(java.util.LinkedHashMap, java.lang.Boolean, java.lang.Boolean, java.lang.Boolean, java.lang.Boolean)

Line | Method
->>   12 | doCall                           in BootStrap$_closure1
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    308 | evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock in grails.util.Environment
|    301 | executeForEnvironment . . . . .  in     ''
|    277 | executeForCurrentEnvironment     in     ''
|    334 | innerRun . . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|    166 | run                              in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker . . . . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run                              in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in java.lang.Thread
```

Here's the domain class AppUser

```
package css.infotech.edu

 class AppUser {

transient springSecurityService

String username
String password
boolean enabled
boolean accountExpired
boolean accountLocked
boolean passwordExpired

static hasMany = [ package: Package]

static transients = ['springSecurityService']

static constraints = {
    username blank: false, unique: true
    password blank: false
}

static mapping = {
    password column: '`password`'
}

Set<Role> getAuthorities() {
    UserRole.findAllByUser(this).collect { it.role } as Set
}
}
```

and here's my bootstrap.groovy

```
import css.infotech.edu.Role
import css.infotech.edu.AppUser
import css.infotech.edu.UserRole

  class BootStrap {

  def init = { servletContext ->

     def adminRole = new Role(authority: 'ROLE_ADMIN').save(flush: true)
     def userRole = new Role(authority: 'ROLE_USER').save(flush: true)

     def testUser = new AppUser(username: 'knownuser', password:'realpassword', true, true, true, true)
     testUser.save(flush: true)

     UserRole.create testUser, adminRole, true

     assert AppUser.count() == 1
     assert Role.count() == 2
     assert UserRole.count() == 1
   }

   def destroy = {
  }
}
```

further, would it be possible to use SAML (Shibboleth) to source roles instead of LDAP?

Comment: Your error doesn't have anything to do with CAS.  The exception is thrown because you're not calling the `AppUser` constructor properly.  Try `new AppUser(username: 'knownuser', password:'realpassword', enabled: true, accountExpired: true, accountLocked: false, passwordExpired: false)`.

Comment: And I say WOOT! upon you, thanks .. that was it. I had tried qualifying the constructors but some how had missed it.